# How bash and other smart shells can find executable files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

They handle executable elfs, scripts and symbolic links from PATH, however what the algorithm of this doing? <strike>I'm afraid of</strike> I cannot find a source code of this part of a shell.

UDP: Oh, I'm stupid. It looks for EACH executable file in PATH, either directory or ordinary file.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You type in "my_command". The shell then looks in each directory in your PATH for "my_command" in the order that the directories are listed in PATH. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @kaylum I think he wants the source code of Bash section where this part is dealt with.

Comment: @SuvP Maybe. But the title is asking a general shell question. And the question body seems to ask for some code to work out the answer to that question. But the general question does not need source code to be answered. So it is not clear whether OP just wants to know the general answer or the specific source code. Let's wait for clarification from OP.

Comment: The shell doesn't care about *what* the executable is; that's handled by the `exec*` family of system calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the actual search is performed by `find_user_command_in_path()` in [findcmd.c:553](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/findcmd.c#n553).

The algorithm to search for a command `${foo}` is basically:

- check if `${foo}` is absolute: if it is return this path and stop searching
- iterate over all elements in PATH: `for p in ${PATH}`

  - construct a path `${p}/${foo}` and see if it exists

    - if it exists and is executable return this path and stop searching

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in this area, but I'm almost perfectly sure that on Linux the executable bit in file permissions is all that matters. No sophisticated algorithm needed.

Comment: The shell has to locate the file before it can check the permissions.. The question is about how the shell locates the file.

Comment: I see, maybe it is. But marar seems to understand that the shell looks in directories specified in `PATH`, so I concluded the question may be about identifying the files that are *executable*.

Comment: The question asks *How bash and other smart shells can find executable files*, which indicates that @marar understands the PATH is used but not how it is actually *searched*. That *search algorithm* is what the question asks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that we have a file called hello in the current directory, and that the file contains just one line: echo "hello"

1. If you ran chmod 755 on the file and and you subsequently execute the file, then the bash shell will look through every path that you have listed in the PATH variable of say .bashrc, starting with the first path, until it locates the first path that contains your hello executable. Think of PATH as a linked list and think of the bash shell as going through the linked list of paths, path by path. If the bash shell is not running the hello executable that you want it to run, you have one option: put your hello executable in any one of the preceeding paths.
2. I am lazy. I don't bother to turn hello into an executable i.e. I am not running the chmod command and I just run

   bash hello

where the bash shell is going to look for the hello file in the current directory, fork a bash process and the forked bash process is going to run the hello file before the forked bash process dies.

I am using the bash shell as an example but any other shell will behave the same way.